# Does my motherboard support Multi-Core Processors?

Tags: motherboard, upgrade, multi-core

My specs:

```
Hewlett-Packard HP d530 SFF motherboard
CPU Properties  
CPU Type - Intel Pentium 4, 2800 MHz (21 x 133)
CPU Alias - Northwood
CPU Stepping - D1
Package Type - 478 Pin uPGA
Instruction Set - x86, MMX, SSE, SSE2
Original Clock - 2800 MHz
Min / Max CPU Multiplier - 21x / 21x
Engineering Sample - No
L1 Trace Cache - 12K Instructions
L1 Data Cache - 8 KB
L2 Cache - 512 KB  (On-Die, ECC, ATC, Full-Speed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your board supports socket 478, which is only for Pentium 4 and Celeron processors, so sorry, but no.

http://www.eggxpert.com/forums/thread/560894.aspx (I searched without the quotes "d530 SFF motherboard socket", and got many results confirming your socket).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_478

Comment: Does my motherboard support 64 bit processor?

Comment: Still trying to find out...you may already have a 64-bit capable processor, but not sure what this means 100%: "In 2004, the initial 32-bit x86 instruction set of the Pentium 4 microprocessors was extended by the 64-bit x86-64 set". I think you do, but trying to verify. You have a "Northwood" processor: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_4#Northwood

Comment: OK, I am pretty sure yours is not currently a 64-bit processor as I thought may be possible: http://ark.intel.com/products/27495/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-supporting-HT-Technology-2_80-GHz-512K-Cache-800-MHz-FSB I am also pretty sure that if you found one that was on that Wikipedia page, it would work. That said, the cost of that processor probably would not be worth it considering you can get a used 2.1 GHz board and dual-core processor on eBay for only $20 more. They are very cheap.

Comment: @KCotreau let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/952/discussion-between-robrok-and-kcotreau)